# (re)implement dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, embedded, arm

I am working in an ARM7 embedded environment. The compiler I am using does not support the full C++ functionality. One feature it does NOT support is dynamic type casting.

Is there a way to implement `dynamic_cast<>()`?

I looked for code using Google, but no luck so far. Any ideas? Any links?

UPDATE:

Due to the comments... I'm using the ARM(R) IAR C/C++ Compiler.

Comment: If your compiler doesn't support RTTI wouldn't reimplementing `dynamic_cast` include to add a whole RTTI system?

Comment: I don't think this is really a C question, so it might be helpful to remove the C tag.

Comment: Is it possible for you to not use `dynamic_cast`? It can often indicate a broken design.

Comment: @Peter Wood: Yes indeed I realized I can do things without type casting. And I guess you could say it is/was a broken design. But I wonder. I think I will read more about type casting. t seems like it should be avoided as much as possible. I wasn't really aware of that.

Comment: The simplest thing to do is switch to a compiler that does support it! Some embedded systems compilers support it but have it as a default disabled option (because of the memory overhead and run-time performance); you should make sure that is not the case here.  It would have helped perhaps if you had stated what compiler you are using.

Answer (score 4):

dynamic_cast is useful when casting away from the base class, something to be done as little as possible.

Assuming the instances when you want to do this are limited, then a virtual function like `GetMessageType()` in a base class returning a different value in each derived class will let you know what to static_cast down to.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the COM concepts -- objects there have a method to return a pointer to a specific interface that is selected by an identifier not built into the compiler (in COM's case, a UUID).

Depending on your application, a simple integer may do:

```
class castable {
    virtual bool cast_to(int desttype) = 0;
};

class type1 : public castable { public: static int const type = 1; };
class type2 : public castable { public: static int const type = 2; };

class impl : public type1, public type2 {
    virtual void *cast_to(int desttype) {
        switch(desttype) {
            case type1::type: return static_cast<type1 *>(this);
            case type2::type: return static_cast<type2 *>(this);
            default: return 0;
        }
    }
};
```

Then, if templates work correctly:

```
template<typename T> T my_dynamic_cast(castable *obj) {
    return reinterpret_cast<T>(obj.cast_to(T::type));
}
```

You can then create objects normally, and cast between base class pointers:

```
impl im;
type1 *t1 = &im;     // Implicit, as it is a base class
type2 *t2 = my_dynamic_cast<type2 *>(t1);
```

The only difficulty here is assigning the identifiers.

Comment: This looks like a nice solution. Had to eliminate a few typos. But I don't really understand how this works eventually. A little main(){...} would be of GREAT help. Thanks already for this answer and sorry for not getting back to this for a while.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends exactly how much of `dynamic_cast` functionality you need.

Most often, I see `dynamic_cast` used to perform a checked conversion: `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(p)` will return `0` if ultimately `p` real type is not `Derived*`...

... but even this is quite complicated:

- What if `p` is really `EvenMoreDerived` and not just `Derived` ?
- What is `p` inherits from `Base` multiple times ?

And it can get even more hairy:

- `static_cast` is not able to cross `virtual` inheritance boundaries.
- `static_cast` is not suitable for cross-branches conversions (you have to pass through the common ancestor)
- `static_cast` cannot emulate the `dynamic_cast<void*>()` conversion.

So, if you want a *simple barebone functionality* of checked conversion up the inheritance tree in case of single inheritance without `virtual` thrown in, then you can actually implement it in user-land.

Otherwise, without RTTI support, you will be quite stuck.

---

Example of simple (dumb ?) implementation, beginning with the support from the class hierarchy:

```
class Base {
public:
  typedef size_t ID;

  virtual ID getID() const = 0;

protected:
  static ID NextID() { static ID = 0; return ID++; }

// much more stuff
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
  static ID GetID() { static ID id = Base::NextID(); return id; }

  virtual ID getID() const { return GetID(); }
};
```

We can leverage this with:

```
template <typename To>
To* dyn_cast(Base* b) {
  if (b and b->getID() == To::GetID()) { return static_cast<To*>(b); }
  return 0;
}
```

---

However, this only work for *one level*. So, if `MoreDerived` inherits from `Derived` then:

```
MoreDerived md;
assert(dyn_cast<Derived>(&md)); // failure ...
```

so it really gets tricky here.

A possible approach is to check from the top of the hierarchy, to the bottom.

```
class Base {
public:
  template <typename To>
  bool isa() const {
    return this->match(To::GetID());
  }

protected:
  typedef size_t ID;

  static ID NextID() { static ID id = 0; return id++; }

  virtual bool match(ID) const { return false; }
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
  static ID GetID() { static ID id = NextID(); return id; }

protected:
  virtual bool match(ID id) const { return id == GetID() || Base::match(id); }
};

class MostDerived: public Derived {
public:
  static ID GetID() { static ID id = NextID(); return id; }

protected:
  virtual bool match(ID id) const { return id == GetID() || Derived::match(id); }
};
```

Slightly more complex, but now:

```
template <typename To, typename From>
To const* dyn_cast(From const* f) {
  if (f and f->template isa<To>()) { return static_cast<To const*>(f); }
  return 0;
}

template <typename To, typename From>
To* dyn_cast(From* f) { return const_cast<To*>(dyn_cast<To>((From const*)f)); }
```

Test case:

```
int main() {
  Derived derived; MostDerived mostDerived;
  Base* d = &derived, * md = &mostDerived;

  if (dyn_cast<Derived>(d)) { std::cout << "Derived -> Derived: ok\n"; }
  else                      { std::cout << "Derived -> Derived: ko\n"; }

  if (dyn_cast<MostDerived>(md)) { std::cout << "MostDerived -> MostDerived : ok\n"; }
  else                           { std::cout << "MostDerived -> MostDerived : ko\n"; }

  if (dyn_cast<Derived>(md)) { std::cout << "MostDerived -> Derived : ok\n"; }
  else                       { std::cout << "MostDerived -> Derived : ko\n"; }

  if (dyn_cast<MostDerived>(d)) { std::cout << "Derived -> MostDerived: ko\n"; }
  else                          { std::cout << "Derived -> MostDerived: ok\n"; }
}
```

[In action at ideone](http://ideone.com/yxPd3).

It is still very incomplete compared to a true `dynamic_cast` though. But it should cover most uses already.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it possible to just cast your pointer and start using it as the other type of object?

```
Foo* f = new Foo();
f.baz();
Bar* b = (Bar*)f;
b.bop();
```

Comment: -1 This is not what the OP wants, dynamic cast throw exception or return a null pointer in case of bad cast, the C-like cast doesn't do that.